# React: weird stale closure issue with `useRef`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a `useDebounce` util hook.

```js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let timer = 0;
  return (...args) => {    
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      fn(...args);
    }, delay);
  };
}

function useDebounce(fn, delay) {
  const ref = React.useRef(fn);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current = fn;
  }, [fn]);

  return useMemo(() => debounce(ref.current, delay), [delay]);
}
```

I use `ref` to store the callback and update it using `useLayoutEffect` so the consumers of the API don't need to memoize their own callback. And also I wanted to preemptively answer that I know how `useMemo` works and I know you can memo the callback i.e. `fn` passed in `useDebounce` from outside but I don't want that burden on the users of the API so I did it myself.

Here is a live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/closure-bug-xcvyd?file=/src/App.js

Now the function I want to denounce is

```js
  const increment = () => {
    console.log(count);
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
```

so I just passed it in to `useDebounce` but it seems like the function ended up with stale closure over `count` because it only updates `count` from `0` -> `1` and then after that no matter how many times you click on the button it doesn't update anymore.

Yes I know I can write `setCount(c => c + 1);` to work around this problem.

But what perplexed me is that, if I rewrite `useMemo(() => debounce(ref.current, delay), [delay]);` to `return useMemo(() => debounce((...args) => ref.current(...args), delay), [ delay ]);` then this problem is fixed automatically.

I cannot seem to understand how `(...args) => ref.current(...args)` is fixing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look what is happening step by step.

- You are placing `fn` inside ref.
- You are updating ref with new value
- You are passing `fn` to  debounce inside `useMemo` and this is where the error is.

On next render, you are again updating `ref`, but memoized function don't use it at all. It remembers reference to very first passed `fn` and this will change only when user of your hook will change delay.

In fixed example, with arrow function this is what happens:

- You are placing `fn` inside ref
- You are updating ref with new value
- You are memoizing function that closures `ref` and will look inside it on each call, so it will pick the freshest `fn` value from ref.

```js
function useDebounce(fn, delay) {
  // storing function into ref
  const ref = React.useRef(fn);
  
  // updating function after memoization, and on each render when function changed
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current = fn;
  }, [fn]);

  return useMemo(function() {
    // here you are referencing current `fn`
    // The very first `fn` that was passed into hook
    // ref don't play role here - you are passing `ref.current`
    let fnToDebounce = ref.current 
    return debounce(fnToDebounce, delay)
  }, [delay]);
}

function useDebounce(fn, delay) {
  // storing function into ref
  const ref = React.useRef(fn);
  
  // updating function after memoization, and on each render when function changed
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current = fn;
  }, [fn]);

  return useMemo(function() {
    // Here  you are closuring reference to `ref` and `fnToDebounce` have no idea what is inside it.
    // When it would be called, it will get ref and only at that point will retrieve `ref.current`, that will be the latest `fn`
    let fnToDebounce = (...args) => ref.current(...args);
    return debounce(fnToDebounce, delay);
  }, [delay]);
}
```

Comment: hmm I am still having trouble understanding this. "On next render, you are again updating ref, but memoized function don't use it at all". why is that? shouldn't the updated `fn` be used via `ref.current` since `ref.current` always points to the fresh `fn`? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference (link to memory) and function is an object. When you pass `ref.current` into `debounce` you passing reference to those first saved `fn`. In second case you are passing function that will access ref via reference and get fresh `current` from it. Sorry, my  English is not very good here. I'll try to annotate your code

Comment: yea I know functions in javascript are callable objects and objects are passed by reference which is really just a bunch of memory pointers. That's exactly where I don't quite get it. by doing `useMemo(() => debounce(ref.current, delay), [delay]);` , we are passing `ref.current` which _is_ updated by `useLayoutEffect` every time `fn` changes right? so shouldn't `ref.current` point to the lastest `fn`?

Comment: No.You are not updating reference to ref.current. You are updating `ref`. It's like `let obj = {a: 1}; obj.a = 2`. If you closured  `obj.a` before changing it to `2`, you will forever get `1`. But if you closure `obj`, you will get it's freshest state whenever your will try to get `obj.a`

Comment: ok I think I kinda get it.... thanks! but I think in the code snippet you just posted you need to explicitly return `debounce(fnToDebounce, delay)` to make it work I think?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll fix it. Was breaking it into parts and missed return.

Comment: Sorry I think I still having a little bit trouble understanding it. You said because I closed over `obj.a`, even if I updated `obj.a` later, it will always return `1` instead `2`. so I made a demo to try to reproduce that https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-night-7l4s0?file=/src/index.js but it seems like it is getting updated correctly.... could you take a look at the link

Comment: I rewrote your same example, but without react stuff. Maybe it would be more clear: https://jsbin.com/buruhecezo/3/edit?js,console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229869/discussion-between-mr-hedgehog-and-joji).

Answer (score 1):

This will pass `ref.current` to debounce.

```
useMemo(() => debounce(ref.current, delay), [delay]);
```

It's equivalent to this:

```
useMemo(() => debounce(fn, delay), [delay]);
```

The memoized function will only be created the first time you call the hook. The closure will have the original `increment` which encloses the original `count`, but `ref` is not enclosed.

In this version, however, you pass a lambda function with `ref` enlosed.

```
return useMemo(() => debounce((...args) => ref.current(...args))
```

Each time useDebounce is called, you change the `increment` function to a new one with the current `count` enclosed. `useLayoutEffect` will update ref, which is also enclosed in the memoized/debounced function.

So in the second case you have a nested chain of closures, which ensures that the debounce function will always have access to the latest `count`.

```
useMemo -> debounce -> (lambda) -> ref -> current -> increment -> count
```

You could simplify the code by just using the useCallback hook instead of making your own. But you must pass an updater function to setCount, to avoid a stale `count` value.

```
const increment = React.useCallback(
  debounce(() => setCount((n) => n + 1), delay),
  [setCount, delay]
)
```

[Code Sandbox demo of this](https://codesandbox.io/s/debounce-increment-isze3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: by "The memoized function will only be created the first time you call the hook." you meant this function `() => debounce(ref.current, delay)` is created only once?  then shouldn't the correct version i.e. `() => debounce((...args) => ref.current(...args), delay)` be only created once? I am still trying to understand why the second form will have the fresh `fn` or `ref.current`

Comment: You are passing a new function each time, but `useMemo` will only memoize the initial one, and return that, unless you change the dependency `delay`.

Comment: yea exactly. but that still doesn't answer my question: which is why `() => debounce((...args) => ref.current(...args), delay)` solved the issue. So you said `useMemo(() => debounce(ref.current, delay), [delay]);` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => debounce(fn, delay), [delay]);` so every time `delay` doesn't change, the `useMemo` hook will use the prev memo'ed function which is `() => debounce(fn, delay)`. For `() => debounce((...args) => ref.current(...args), delay)` , I wonder is it because using a lamda we defer the evaluation of `ref.current` so it can preserve the fresh closure?

Comment: No. The closure is not fresh. But it does contain the `ref` singleton in the closure. The `ref` will always refer to the same object for the full lifecycle of the component. So when you change `ref.current` to be a new `increment` function with a new `count` enclosed, the lambda function will have the new `ref.current`, too.

Comment: I should mention that my answer and Mr HedgeHog's answer are only different in wording. We are trying to explain exactly the same thing. Closures can be very confusing, and when you add in the memoization from react hooks, it adds another level of complexity.

Comment: I think I have no problem understanding that the `ref` will always refer to the same object for the full lifecycle of the component. Anyway, thanks for the explanation. I think I understand why `(...args) => ref.current(...args)` works while `ref.current` doesn't. I wonder if there is a name for this pattern i.e. when you need to pass a callback to another function, instead of passing the reference directly you pass a new anonymous function that encloses the reference to that function?

Answer (score -1):

This is a standard useDebounce

```js
function useDebounce(value, delay) {
  // State and setters for debounced value
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      // Update debounced value after delay
      const handler = setTimeout(() => {
        setDebouncedValue(value);
      }, delay);

      // Cancel the timeout if value changes (also on delay change or unmount)
      // This is how we prevent debounced value from updating if value is changed ...
      // .. within the delay period. Timeout gets cleared and restarted.
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(handler);
      };
    },
    [value, delay] // Only re-call effect if value or delay changes
  );

  return debouncedValue;
}
```